# How to display the price in 2 currencies in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I have installed WPML for adding a currency selector on my Woocommerce product pages, everything's fine!

But my question is : can I display my price in 2 different currencies? For example, when the $ CAD is selected, the price would show like this 0,00 $ (0,00 €) but if the currency in the selector is €, the price would show like this 0,00 € (0,00 $)

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the filter `woocommerce_get_price_html`,

```
  add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_price_html, 99, 2);
  function my_price_html( $price, $product ){
         return 'Was:' . str_replace( '<ins>', ' Now:<ins>', $price );
  }.
```